# What is the correct response code when no content is POSTed to a REST resource that expects content?

Tags: rest, post

What is the correct response code when no content is `POSTed` to a resource that expects content?

```
POST http://localhost:10545/api/tokens HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:10545
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The response in this case would be a '400 Bad Request'.

### [400 Bad Request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html)

> The request had bad syntax or was inherently impossible to be satisfied.

Comment: IS there any other response that's more specific?